# Zeros of multiplicity $>1$

Tags: polynomials, roots

Suppose two polynomials $f,g: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ are given and consider the function
$$h(z,s): \mathbb{C}^2 \to \mathbb{C}: (z,s) \mapsto sg(z) + (1-s)f(z).$$

The book I am reading (Numerically Solving Polynomial Systems with Bertini) states that $h(z,s)$ only has double roots for a fixed $s^\ast$ at roots of $f(g' - f') + f'(g - f)$, but I have no idea how the authors found this formula. ($f'$ denotes the derivative of $f$)

Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$z$ is a double root iff $h(z,s)=0$ and the partial derivative at $z$ is also $0$. Thus $sg(z)+(1-s)f(z)=0$ and
$
sg'(z)+(1-s)f'(z)=0.
$
One can eliminate $s$ from these expressions, as the authors do, by writing the first equation as
$$
s(g-f)=-f
$$
and the second as
$$
s(g'-f')=-f'.
$$
Multiply both sides of the first equation by $g'-f'$ and both sides of the second by $g-f$ to obtain
$$
-f(g'-f')=s(g-f)(g'-f')=-f'(g-f).
$$
Thus $f(g'-f')=f'(g-f)$. (I think this is off from what you wrote by a sign, can you confirm the expression?)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! The authors were right to note that it only requires 'a little algebra'. One last question: are you familiar with the book I cited?

Comment: No, I have never heard of it.

Comment: I checked your computations and did not find a mistake, so I guess it must be  typo in the book then...